# How to get the last two sections of a URL

Tags: asp.net, url, c#-4.0

When the URL is: `http://www.example.com/services/product/Software.aspx` , I need: `"product/Software.aspx"`,

So far I just tried the below code :

```
string[] SplitUrls = Request.RawURL.Split('/');
string CategorynQuery = SplitUrls[SplitUrls.Length - 2] 
                        + SplitUrls[SplitUrls.Length - 1];
```

However, is there some other way to do this using functions IndexOf(), LastIndexOf() etc.. or any other Function? Or any possibility using Substring method ?

Please note that the above URL is just an example, there are around 100 such URls and I need the Last 2 sections for each.

Comment: Your solution fails to add back the slash character separating the last to elements of the split array. Apart from that it looks fine. I would not get too hung up about trying to improve it, if I were you.

Comment: That's why i asked for some better solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, using the **LastIndexOf**, and **Substring**.

```
 string str = "http://www.example.com/services/product/Software.aspx";
        int lastIndexOfBackSlash = str.LastIndexOf('/');
        int secondLastIndex = lastIndexOfBackSlash > 0 ? str.LastIndexOf('/', lastIndexOfBackSlash - 1) : -1;

        string result = str.Substring(secondLastIndex, str.Length - secondLastIndex);
```

I am also checking the presence when getting the second last index - obviously you can alter this depending on your requirements :)

Comment: When getting the second last index in  " str.LastIndexOf('/', lastIndexOfBackSlash - 1) " , Do we look for the char '/' from position 0 to lastIndexOfBackSlash - 1 ?

Comment: No, we know the position of the 2nd last occurrence of / from the end, so what we do is use the Substring and take from the 2nd occurence, till the last character of the string. Which in this case, is  "product/Software.aspx"@FlopScientist

Comment: So it is always getting from the 2nd last occurrence on wards.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Uri class:

```
Uri uri = new Uri("http://myUrl/%2E%2E/%2E%2E");
uri.AbsoluteUri;
uri.PathAndQuery;
```

Comment: PathAndQuery will Give: " Software.aspx" and AbsoluteUri will Give: " services/product/Software.aspx ", Can you confirm?

Answer (score 0):

Not too efficient but a little more elegant:

```
    string url = "http://www.example.com/services/product/Software.aspx";
    var splitted = url.Split('/').Reverse().Take(2).Reverse().ToList();
    var str = string.Format("{0}/{1}", splitted[0], splitted[1]);
```